# how come the IOException isn't working but goes to the InputMismatchException

Tags: java, exception, ioexception

I don't understand why this simple method won't catch the exception but throws another exception. The exception error that pops up is  `java.util.InputMismatchException`.

What can i do so that it catches the `IOException`?

```
public class Throwing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int x = getInt();
            System.out.println(x);
        } catch (IOException a) {
            a.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static int getInt() throws IOException {
        int a = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter an interger: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        a = input.nextInt();
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a look at the [JavaDocs for `Scanner#nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) you will see it's capable of throwing a `InputMismatchException`, among others

Comment: But the goal is that I'm trying to throw an IOException rather than InputMismatch. Is there anything i can do to my code which will help me throw it?

Comment: Trap the `InputMismatchExcception` in the `getInt` method and re-throw it as a `IOException`, passing the `InputMismatchExcception` as the cause

Comment: Can you explain this a little more?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Nevermind i tried it a couple times and got the answer using your guide. Thanks. Can you submit an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the [JavaDocs for Scanner#nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) you will see it's capable of throwing a InputMismatchException, among others

> But the goal is that I'm trying to throw an IOException rather than InputMismatch. Is there anything i can do to my code which will help me throw it?

You will need to trap any possible exceptions and throw a new `IOException` with the old `Exception` as the cause.

```
public static int getInt() throws IOException
{
    int a = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter an interger: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        a = input.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
        throw new IOException("Could not get int from input", ime);
    }
    return a;
}
```

This is, IMHO, not the most brilliant idea, as you may wish to treat the `InputMismatchException` differently from the `IOException` which might be caused when you create a `Scanner`

Comment: What's so wrong about this answer that someone has to downvote it?

Comment: Any one want to shine light onto the reason for the down vote?